# Using WiX to update manifest file

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix-extension

I have a manifest file for an application which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity name="xxx.exe" version="1.1.0.0" type="win32" processorArchitecture="x86" />
  <file name="xxxxxxxx.ocx" hashalg="SHA1">
    <comClass clsid="{4xxxxxxx76-D693-4156-93BA-B938A56F15D3}" description="" threadingModel="apartment" />
    <typelib tlbid="{8xxxxxx-3A75-4708-993D-6E0CD9564072}" version="1.0" helpdir="" flags="control,hasdiskimage" />
  </file>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Assembly numero uno" version="1.1.0.0" type="win32" publicKeyToken="7XXXXXXXXXXXD" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

I want to add a new `<dependency>` section right after the `</dependency>` tag.  The new `<dependency>` should look like this:

```
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Assembly number two" version="1.1.0.0" type="win32" publicKeyToken="7XXXXXXXXXXXD" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

How can I achieve this with Wix?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, consider modifying the manifest at build time. If that's possible, it is much more preferable - always choose build-time complexity over install-time complexity.

It might make sense to leave this for install time only in case `<dependency>` element contents depends on the user input or the target system state. In this case you should use one of the WiX options to modify XML, either [XmlFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlfile.htm) @OleksandrPshenychnyy mentioned, or [XmlConfig](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlconfig.htm). I used the latter one more often, as it seems to be more flexible.

If you decide to go for modifying the manifest at install-time, you can still make your life a bit easier. Add the XML pattern to the manifest at build-time, and only modify the parts dependent on the user input or system state at install time. Let's say it is `assemblyIdentity/version` attribute. Then the WiX snippet might look like this:

```
<util:XmlConfig Id="VersionChange" ElementPath="assembly/dependency/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[\[]@name='Assembly number two'[\]]" File="$(var.Manifest)" Name="version" Action="create" Node="value" On="install" PreserveModifiedDate="yes" Value="1.1.0.0" />
```

Note the square brackets escaping technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WisUtilExtention library with XmlFile Element to perform some manipulations with XML file. For more details visit [this link](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlfile.htm)